react native modal does not get rendered on IOS
I have a react-native: "0.74.3" project and I want to show a modal to my users.
So I intalled  react-native-modal: "13.0.1" into my project. I developed the way I want to show the modal, it works for android simulator but it does not work for ios emulators and physical devices.
Here is my folder structure:
src
├── modules
│   └── folder
│       ├── queries
│       ├── Folder.tsx
│       ├── FolderContainer.tsx
│       ├── FolderLongPressMenu.tsx
│       ├── FolderModalItem.tsx
│       ├── FolderMoveModal.tsx
│       ├── NoFoldersComponent.tsx
├── navigation
│   └── HomeStack.tsx
├── routes
│   ├── private-routes
│   │   ├── BottomTabs.tsx
│   │   └── PrivateRoutes.tsx
│   ├── public-routes
│   └── main.tsx
├── screens
│   └── home
│       └── HomeScreen.tsx

In my HomeStack.tsx I have HomeScreen component called. In HomeScreen I have FolderContainer, and many Folder components inside of it.
Here is the Folder component where I use FolderMoveModal:
 <>
            <PressableFolderBox
                className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center mb-4"
                onPress={handleFolderClicked}
                onLongPress={handleLongPress}
            >
                <FolderSvgBox className="w-full">
                    <FolderSvgBox className="w-full h-20">
                        <FolderSvg width="100%" height="100%" />
                    </FolderSvgBox>
                    <FormProvider {...methods}>
                        {folder.id === recentCreatedFolderId ? (
                            <AppTextInput
                                containerStyle={{ width: '100%', height: 20, flex: 1 }}
                                inputStyle={{ color: 'black', fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold', fontSize: 10, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderWidth: 0, borderBottomColor: Colors.primary }}
                                ref={inputRef}
                                name="folderName"
                                defaultValue={folder.name}
                                showErrorInternally={true}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <StyledText className="text-xs text-center" style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold', fontSize: 10 }}>
                                {folder.name}
                            </StyledText>
                        )}
                        {formErrors.map((error, index) => (
                            <StyledText key={index} className="text-xs text-red-500 text-center">
                                {error}
                            </StyledText>
                        ))}
                    </FormProvider>

                    <StyledText className="text-xs text-center" style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Light', fontSize: 10 }}>
                        {`${folder.innerItemsCount} öğe`}
                    </StyledText>
                </FolderSvgBox>
            </PressableFolderBox>
            <FolderLongPressMenu
                folder={folder}
                isMenuVisible={isMenuVisible}
                closeMenu={handleCloseMenu}
                openModal={() => moveModalRef?.current?.show()} />

            <FolderMoveModal
                ref={moveModalRef}
                onClose={handleCloseMoveModal}
                onMove={() => { console.log('move') }} />

        </>

and for the final detail, this is the implementation of FolderMoveModal
const FolderMoveModal = forwardRef(({ onClose, onMove }: FolderMoveModalProps, ref) => {
    const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const [selectedFolderId, setSelectedFolderId] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [filteredFolders, setFilteredFolders] = useState<UserFolder[]>([]);
    const [searchUserFoldersByName] = useMutation<searchUserFoldersByNameMutation, searchUserFoldersByNameMutationVariables>(searchUserFoldersByNameM);

    useImperativeHandle(
        ref,
        () => ({
            show: () => {
                console.log("show")
                setIsModalVisible(true);
            },
            hide: () => {
                console.log("hide")
                setIsModalVisible(false);
            },
        }),
        [],
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("isModalVisible", isModalVisible)
    }, [isModalVisible]);


    const methods = useForm<FormValues>({
        defaultValues: {
            folderName: '',
        },
        resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
        mode: 'onSubmit'
    });

    const debouncedSearch = useRef(_.debounce((value) => {
        if (!value || value.length < 2) {
            setFilteredFolders([]);
            return;
        }
        searchUserFoldersByName({
            variables: { folderName: value },
            onCompleted: (data) => {
                setFilteredFolders(data.searchUserFoldersByName as UserFolder[]);
            },
            onError: (error) => {
                console.error('Error searching folders:', error);
            }
        });
    }, 500)).current;

    const handleSearchChange = useCallback((text: string) => {
        methods.setValue('folderName', text);
        debouncedSearch(text);
    }, [debouncedSearch, methods]);

    const handleFolderSelect = useCallback((folderId: string) => {
        setSelectedFolderId(folderId);
    }, [setSelectedFolderId]);

    const handleMove = useCallback(() => {
        if (selectedFolderId) {
            onMove(selectedFolderId);
            onClose();
        }
    }, [selectedFolderId, onMove, onClose]);

    return (
        <View>
            <Modal
                isVisible={isModalVisible}
                onBackdropPress={onClose}
            >
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>Klasörü Taşı</Text>
                        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                            <FormProvider {...methods}>
                                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                                    <AppTextInput
                                        inputStyle={styles.input}
                                        name="folderName"
                                        placeholder="Klasör ara..."
                                        value={methods.watch('folderName')}
                                        onChangeText={handleSearchChange}
                                        showErrorInternally={false}
                                    />
                                </View>
                            </FormProvider>
                        </View>
                        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                            {filteredFolders.length > 0 ? (
                                <AppGrid items={filteredFolders.map(folder => (
                                    <FolderModalItem key={folder.id} folder={folder} onClick={() => handleFolderSelect(folder.id)} />
                                ))} />
                            ) : (
                                <Text style={styles.noSearchedItemText}>Taşıma yapmak istediğiniz klasörü arayın</Text>
                            )}

                        </ScrollView>
                        <View style={styles.buttonsContainer}>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onClose}>
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>İptal</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.moveButton]} onPress={handleMove}>
                                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Taşı</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>

    );
});

The issue is, I can't see the modal rendered in IOS devices even tho isModalVisible value is true but it works for android simulators. If you guys have any idea then I'm open to hear'em.
Developer notes

I tried using it with setTimeOut it worked for a couple of times but I didn't want to depend on that.
If you click on a Folder component, it pushes a new Home screen to the HomeStack. Just wanted to mention this, maybe it helps.

Thanks already!
